# Using a for loop and the rand to generate 100 random numbers and print out the smalles and biggest

Tags: c++, random

Using a for loop and the rand to generate 100 random numbers and print out the smalles and biggest. Any guidance if im heading in the right direction.

```
int main()
{
    int x = rand();
    for( x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        if( x < x )
        {
            cout << "Small numbers: " << endl;
            cout << x << endl;
        }
        if ( x > x )
        {
            cout << "Big numbers: " << endl;
            cout << x << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Um, you really need more than one variable here.

Comment: You'll need to add two variables.  One named smallest, the other named largest.  Show their values after the loop completes.

Comment: You want to save the current roll, the maximum roll, the lowest roll, and the number of rolls you already did. Try to figure out what you need to do. Don't name your variables `x`, give them meaningful names like `currentNumber` or `lowestValue`.

Comment: You mean something like if ( x > x2 ), where x is being check againts another random number generated?

Comment: That and you generate your random number *before* you loop over it so it will print the same line 100 times. call your variables something like `min_x` and `max_x`

Comment: Imagine you were rolling dice in real life and had a piece of paper on which you could write and update the current lowest and highest numbers seen so far. Then think about how that can translate to your code.

Comment: @JL22 Think about what `x < x` means. If `x` is 5, is `x < x`? No. Five is not less than five. If `x` is 6, is `x < x` no. Is there any integer value at all where `x < x`?

Comment: What do we do now that the homework tag is gone?

Comment: For the smallest you should save a X value, and check if the next X value is lower than the one you saved, and then, save it again... the same idea for the biggest!

Comment: I see what you guys are saying appreaciate the help thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>



using namespace std;


int main()
{


   int smallest = INT_MAX;
   int largest = 0;

   for( int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
   {
      int randomNumber = rand() % 100 + 1; 
      cout << "Next number: " << randomNumber ;
      if( randomNumber > largest )
      {
        largest = randomNumber ;
      }

      if ( randomNumber  < smallest )
      {
        smallest = randomNumber ;
      }
    }

    cout << "Smallest number: " << smallest;
    cout << "Largest number:"<< largest;
    system("pause");

}
```

Comment: please fix indentation!

Comment: this is wrong ! are you comparing values of loop index and largest/smallest?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo!

Answer (score 3):

```
if( x < x )
```

and

```
if (x > x)
```

will never be true. Your logic is not right.

You may do something like the following:

```
int main()
{
    //set up seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    double min = 1000; //you can also use numeric limits
    double max = -1000;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
       double r = rand(); //you can also generate rand in given range
       if (r > max)
       {
          max = r;
       }
       if (r < min)
       {
          min = r;
       }
    }
    cout << min  << " " << max <<endl;
    cin.get(); //don't use system pause
}
```

Comment: *"You should first generate 100 random numbers and store them,then find smallest and biggest."* The additional space isn't needed at all.

Comment: @Zeta I agree. I was trying to be simple since OP does not seem to have enough programming experience. so correct first then optimize is my intention.

Comment: Storing 100 numbers isn't simpler.

Comment: @FredLarson I'd better remove that sentence. thanks.

Comment: `rand()` returns an integer value in the range `[0, RAND_MAX]`. There is no truncation storing the result in an int, and no particular reason for using a `double` instead.

Comment: @PeteBecker sorry, I remembered wrongly, I checked the doc, you are right. thanks! updated.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing is, that you have to generate new random int each time you cross the loop, so you want something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <limits>


using namespace std;


int main()
{

int x = rand();
int min=RAND_MAX;
int max=0;

for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    x = rand();

    if( x < min )
    {
        cout << "Small numbers: " << endl;
        cout << x << endl;
        min=x;
    }

    if ( x > max )
    {
        cout << "Big numbers: " << endl;
        cout << x << endl;
        max=x;
    }
}


system("pause");

 }
```

Comment: Using `x` as the loop control variable and as the value of the generated random value will not work.

Comment: well, rather yes, might be true, typo

Comment: Not so much a typo as a copy of the original code. `<g>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not going to do anything because you're comparing the same variable.

You will need to set up a list or array in order to sort, and then compare elements, rearrange accordingly, and then iterate over the list and display in order.

C++ standard libraries can help this process:

[Sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

Comment: Yes, that would work, but it's total overkill for this task. All you need to track is the largest and smallest value seen to date.